# Is it possible to send google analytics data to a vendor?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a vendor that would like me to add their GA tracking code "UA-XXX-2" to our website. I cannot add their GA tracking code because it will interfere with our GA tracking code "UA-XXX-1". Is there a way I can send GA data to their "UA-XXX-2" UA number without screwing up my analytics for my domain?

AutoLink seemed like it might work, but AutoLink seems to be for when you own and maintain both domains. [GA AutoLink](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autolink)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [Multiple tracking codes on web pages](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en) are possible.

Comment: You can also link an additional account to your analytics page and grant them access to your analytics data.

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you @Blazemonger for the link you provided. [Working with Multiple Tracking Objects](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers).

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple tracking codes on your site with no issue at all.

You can also just give them access to your existing GA web property.